# cell.image is deprecated

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, deprecated

I want to add pictures to every row in `UITableView`.

When I use `cell.image = [UIImage imgNamed:@"xxx.png"];`
 it jumps out a warning saying `"image is deprecated"`.

Though it works, are there any alternatives that do not produce a warning?

Comment: Any warning about something being deprecated will usually be well documented in the you guessed it... [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/#section=Resource%20Types&topic=Reference).

Comment: Just copy your question title and paste that in google... You will get the answer easily...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, use `cell.imageView.image` as described in the documentation:

> **image**
>
> The image to use as content for the cell. (Deprecated in iOS 3.0. Instead use the imageView property to get UIImageView object and then get or set the encapsulated image.)

Comment: thanks! Just like cell.textLabel.text instead of cell.text lol!

Answer (score 3):

Use This Code

> Cell.imageView.image

Remove The Warning Of image deprecated

Thanks